# object of object interface typescript

Tags: typescript

I have an object for an array that can be the following

```
{
 'value1': 1,
 'value2': 2
}
```

or

```
{
 'value1': 'a',
 'value2': 'b'
}
```

or

```
{
 'value1': {'sub1': 1, 'sub2': 2},
 'value2': {'sub1': 1, 'sub2': 2}
}
```

I wanted to type this like this :

```
export interface TableRow {
  [key: string]: string | number | ([key: string] : string) | ([key: string] : number)
}
```

but it doesn't work.

Is this the only way possible ?

```
export interface TableRow {
  [key: string]: string | number | object
}
```

Comment: This looks like just a typo to me (e.g., `interface TableRow { [key: string]: string | number | { [key: string]: string } | { [key: string]: number } }`).  Is that what you mean by "it doesn't work"?  Usually a [mcve] should explicitly describe what the problem is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `()` with `{}`:

```
export interface TableRow {
    [key: string]: string | number | { [key: string]: string } | { [key: string]: number }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

i think it better to do this neatly with two interfaces

```
export interface TableCell {
    [key: string]: string | number
}

export interface TableRow {
    [key: string]: string | number | TableCell
}
```